How can I list all entries that have a populated Freeform Form field?
The Freeform Form field can either be a direct custom field of the entry, or it may be inside a Matrix field's blocks or be a Super Table field.
Ideally, I'd like to do this performantly, and either as a Twig template, or a custom page in the backend which the client can reference.
The goal is for the client to be able to see which "pages" (entries) use which Freeform forms. With how the site is set up, there are no hard-coded forms; they are all selected and rendered via a Freeform Form field (Solspace\Freeform\FieldTypes\FormFieldType).
